# Basic Puppet manifest dependency/syntax issue

Tags: puppet

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and the examples I have googled seem to suggest this is allowed (I basically copied/pasted).

```
#
# Configure MySQL
#

package { 'mysql-server':
  ensure => installed,
}

service { 'mysql':
  ensure => running,
  enable => true
}

exec { 'set-mysql-password':
  unless  => 'mysqladmin -uroot -proot status',
  command => "mysqladmin -uroot password ALEXWASHERE",
  path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin'],
  require => Service['mysql'];
}

#mysql:db { 'apps':
#  user     => 'aerospace_erp',
#  password => 'ALEXWASHERE',
#  host     => 'localhost',
#  grant    => ['SHOW VIEW', 'SELECT', 'UPDATE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE']
#}
```

This results in the following errors:

```
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[mysql]: Could not evaluate: Could not find init script for 'mysql'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[mysql-server]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[set-mysql-password]: Dependency Service[mysql] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[set-mysql-password]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

Not sure whats going on???

Alex

Comment: Not sure why but the "service" block must have "require" specified as follows (  require => Package['mysql-server'],) -- this corrected the missing dependency. Although I assumed "package" block would have done this already -- seems redundant -- what am I miss understanding???

Comment: Puppet does not use the order you declare resources in, instead it figures out what order to use based on dependencies. There is no way for puppet to know that the package and service you declared are related, so it tried to start the service before installing the package.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux OS,

service is `mysqld` not `mysql`

```
service { "mysqld" : ensure => running,}
```

Comment: I did change that...is that what fixed the problem? Not the require => Package['mysql-server'] as I indicated?\

Comment: Both must be in order. I take issue with the assertion that "in Linux OS", the service title takes a certain form. It really depends on the package you are using. It is safest to use a Puppet module such as `puppetlabs-mysql`.